# Select tree path in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, recursion, tree, hierarchical

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
| CategoryId |          Name | CategoryParentId |
|------------|---------------|------------------|
|          0 |  Tech Support |           (null) |
|          1 | Configuration |                0 |
|          2 |     Questions |                1 |
|          3 |         Sales |           (null) |
|          4 |     Questions |                3 |
|          5 |         Other |           (null) |
```

This is the output I desire when a query the ID 2 (for example):

Tech Support/Configuration/Questions

How do I do this without having to do multiple joins?

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45a11)

EDIT: Not sure if is the best way to do this, but I solved by creating a function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION get_full_tree (CategoryId int) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)

BEGIN
SET @CategoryParentId = (SELECT CategoryParentId FROM category c WHERE c.CategoryId = CategoryId);
SET @Tree = (SELECT Name FROM category c WHERE c.CategoryId = CategoryId);
WHILE (@CategoryParentId IS NOT NULL) DO
    SET @ParentName = (SELECT Name FROM category c WHERE c.CategoryId = @CategoryParentId);
    SET @Tree = CONCAT(@ParentName, '/', @Tree);
    SET @CategoryParentId = (SELECT CategoryParentId FROM category c WHERE c.CategoryId = @CategoryParentId);
END WHILE;
RETURN @Tree;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I can now do this query:

```
SELECT CategoryId, get_full_tree(CategoryId) FROM category
```

Comment: Not sure if that can be done in one line. You can do SELECT NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE CATEGORYID <= p_CategoryId; and write results into a temp table and then use WHILE loop on the temp table to concat names. Or you can use a cursor to concat names.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table, lets name it as `hierarchy` (could be a better name) where we would store all the ancestry of a category.

```
CREATE TABLE `hierarchy` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

For example in this case for `Questions` i.e. **ID->2** we will have the below entries:

```
id  parent     child
====================            
6     0         2
7     1         2
8     2         2
```

For the whole example the content of the table would be:

```
id       parent     child
===========================
1           0           0
2           3           3
3           5           5
4           0           1
5           1           1
6           0           2
7           1           2
8           2           2
9           3           4
10          4           4
```

Now whenever you want to retrieve the whole ancestry of  node execute the below query:

```
select name from category where id in (select parent from hierarchy where child = 2 order by id ASC)
```

The above query will return all the ancestry names for the `Questions` (ID->2) i.e.

```
name
==================
Tech Support
Configuration
Questions
```

For completeness shake below is the content for `category` table

```
id             Name
============================
0             Tech Support
1             Configuration
2             Questions
3             Sales
4             Questions
5             Other
```

**N.B.** This is just an idea i am sure you can definitely build more elegant solution on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8 or above you can use Common Table Expressions for recursive queries. Query would be the following

```
WITH RECURSIVE CategoryPath (CategoryId, Name, path) AS
(
  SELECT CategoryId, Name, Name as path
    FROM category
    WHERE CategoryParentId IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.CategoryId, c.Name, CONCAT(cp.path, ' / ', c.Name)
    FROM CategoryPath AS cp JOIN category AS c
      ON cp.CategoryId = c.CategoryParentId 
)
SELECT * FROM CategoryPath ORDER BY path;
```